# NSTimer do not work in another thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I have a problem about using NSTimer and the code is as below, I have simplified the code:

```
- (void) mainThreadFun
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(test) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
           [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(test1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    });

}
```

I found that the NSTimer in the mainThread work but the NSTimer in another thread did not work. Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a NSTimer on a background thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304702/), [Problem with thread and NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335114/), [Running a timer within an NSThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083737/), [Threaded NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156452/), [NSThread and NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338891/)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) on a GCD queue. NSTimer requires an [NSRunLoop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/) to operate, and GCD queues do not have an NSRunLoop.

If you want timer functionality with GCD queues, you should be using either [`dispatch_after()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) for a one-shot timer, or a [dispatch_source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW41) for repeating timers.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: That is incorrect. Queues do not get drained by runloops. The only exception is the main runloop does drain the main queue. You're confused because calling `+[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` will actually create one for the current thread if one doesn't exist. But that doesn't mean the runloop is actually running, because it's not.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: Then either you're actually on the main queue or the documentation is wrong. Try pausing in the debugger and look at the backtrace. NSRunLoop is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: BTW, you may be fooling yourself if you're using a `dispatch_sync()` onto a global queue to test this. `dispatch_sync()` will typically run the block on the current thread if it can.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: Well yes, of *course* they're on threads. You can't run code outside of a thread. But they have no run loop. Here's a [sample file](https://gist.github.com/2833771) that demonstrates this. The first `dispatch_sync()` will run on thread 1 with a run loop, but the `dispatch_group_async()` runs on thread 2 with no run loop.